# How do I derive the Sum of Squares sums for an arbitrary ANOVA?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I know it is possible to derive the Sums of Squares sums for a simple one-way CRD ANOVA. It is done by substituting the treatment factors into the total SS equation, then squaring, eliminating terms that sum to zero, and re-factoring to a squared form. As shown in this image:
[image]

However, I need to get the Sum of Squares sums not just for the simple 1-factor CRD case, but also for 2-factor and 3-factor CRDs, 1- 2- and 3-factor partially repeated measures designs, 1- 2- and 3- factor fully repeated measures designs, as well as for RBCDs, and also split-plot designs. Basically every commonly used ANOVA. I haven't found a book or internet reference that simply lists the SS equations for all these designs, so I thought I would just derive them myself.

But, as shown in the picture below, the terms increase very quickly with more than one factor, and I don't even know which terms cancel each other out. For example, the 2-factor CRD case is a lot more complicated already:
[image]

I want to know if there is an algorithm/system for performing these SS derivations, or if there is a reference that simply states the SS equation for each design type, that would be great too. Thanks! Chris

Comment: The Total Sum of Squares in most ANOVAs is the numerator of the variance of the values $Y_i.$ The sums of squares on various rows of the ANOVA table add to this Total sum of squares

Answer (score 0):

*Comment* (in case it disappears for some reason):
The Total Sum of Squares in most ANOVAs is the numerator of the variance of the values of the $Y_i.$ The sums of squares on various rows of the ANOVA table add to this Total sum of squares.

---

I will illustrate my comment with a simple balanced one-way ANOVA
with three levels of the factor. [Fictitious data, sampled using R.]

```
set.seed(2021)
y1 = rnorm(10, 100, 15)
y2 = rnorm(10, 102, 15)
y3 = rnorm(10, 105, 15)
y = c(y1, y2, y3)
g = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=10))

anova(lm(y ~ g))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
g          2  431.2  215.60  0.8359 0.4444
Residuals 27 6964.0  257.93
```

Numerator of variance of the 30 observations:

```
29*var(y)
[1] 7395.207
```

SS(Factor) + SS(Resid), from ANOVA table above:

```
531.2 + 6964.0
[1] 7495.2
```

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for your reply, I do understand that the total sum of squares is equal in value to the partitioned sum of squares for any given anova. However, my question is more about how to derive the partitioned sum of squares equations to begin with. This is because some anova models become quite complicated with repeated measures, blocks, and split-plot-style randomization schemes. I would like to know if there is a way to derive the sum of squares partitions from first-principles. If you have any reference that shows these derivations for each design style, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: In what way is "numerator of variance of $Y_i$'s" not the answer to fundamental question in your title :(`29*var(y)`)? As you say, algebraic details of partition of SS(Tot) in complex design can be challenging. Matrix algebra may make partitioning more transparent. Brownlee's Wiley book from the 1950s shows lots of equations and some derivations for moderately complex designs (partly as a guide to computation on mechanical calculators of the day), without matrix algebra. // R output usually shows components, but sometimes not total.

Comment: Hi Bruce, in my question title, I am using the word 'derive' in the sense of a mathematical proof, and maybe that is where the confusion is. In the top picture, I show a visual representation of the algebraic operations which can be used to 'derive' the partitioned sum of squares equations [ SS-error (green) + SS-treatment (blue) = SS-total (purple), with the yellow and red terms canceling to zero], for the simplest ANOVA case.

Comment: In general, I am interested in a way to discover, i.e. 'derive', the partitioned sum of squares terms for an arbitrary study design. Your answer is correct in that the variance of the Y data points does give the the total sum of squares as it must, but my understanding is that this does not give insight into the sums of squares partition due to the treatments. (Of course, I can plug numbers into R and see if my calculations match up with the computer's, which is helpful too). I will look at the Brownlee book you mention as well, thanks!

Comment: Look at a book that shows partitioning for several simple cases to get an idea of what is involved, maybe starting with SSs for fixed main effects, each of which is based on the variance of means of the levels of an effect. // In my Exmp let `a1,a2,a3` be the 3 level means (each of 10 obs), then , in R: `10*2*var(c(a1,a2,a3))` returns SS(Fact) $431.2104.$